# PM2-runtime restart logs

Tags: docker, pm2

I'm running node js app on Docker and using PM2-runtime to start the application, but I can't see any logs related to the app got restarted.
Is there is a way to check a PM2 daemon logs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By running `pm2 logs` you will also see the restart delay being incremented:

PM2      | App [throw:0] will restart in 100ms

PM2      | App [throw:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2      | App [throw:0] will restart in 150ms

PM2      | App [throw:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

Comment: Pm2 logs is only providing me the streaming logs, but not related to the restart.